# Minimum Java Version required for cn1lib to work

Tags: codenameone

I'm seeing the following error message, I would like to know what is the minimum JDK version required for cn1lib to work. I have searched in the forum to see what is the minimum version and could not find correct reference. Please advise.

Cannot use a cn1lib with java version greater then the project java version
    at com.codename1.build.client.InstallLibsTask.mergeRequiredProperties(InstallLibsTask.java:227)
    at com.codename1.build.client.InstallLibsTask.unzip(InstallLibsTask.java:97)
    at com.codename1.build.client.InstallLibsTask.execute(InstallLibsTask.java:82)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor301.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)

Comment: It's unrelated to the JDK it's related to the project version. If you have an old project it might be a Java 5 project which you could migrate to Java 8. If you specify which cn1lib and what you have in `codenameone_settings.properties` I could help more

Comment: Shai..I found this is due to codenameone_settings file got corrupted. This happens sometimes without any reason. I haven't done any changes recently. Is there something I should be careful about.

Comment: What do you mean by "corrupted"?

Comment: All or some of the build hints and configurations from the file will disappear. Please advise

Comment: That is odd. Is this something that you can reproduce? Did it happen after you did something?

Comment: It is sporadic. Not sure when it happens but I end up realizing when I give the debug build. Thanks

Comment: Which cn1libs do you use? Did you install all of them through the extension manager and are they all up to date?

Comment: Yes. I'm using FingerPrintScanner, NativeLogReader, Connectivity and BountyCastle

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the NativeLogReader cn1lib which defined `codename1.arg.java.version=8` which might conflict with valid Java 8 projects.

I've created this pull request to fix that: https://github.com/jsfan3/CN1Libs-NativeLogsReader/pull/1 once it's done the author would need to submit an update and you'd need to update the cn1lib from the extension manager.